# Continuous interest rate in differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In [this](https://youtu.be/te6Mplq3DCU?t=837) video(don't have to click) the professor sets up a problem:

> Let $y$ be the money in the bank account and $r$ be the continuous
>   interest rate, then: $$\dfrac{dy}{dt} = ry$$
>   models the bank account.

What's the time unit here? Does the given $r$ represent the *simple interest* per year? Why is he calling it *continuous interest*?
I don't see how  $dy = ry\times dt$ represents the change in account?
Highly appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: When calculating simple interest, we evaluate interest once per a fixed time period (eg. per day, or month, or year). To get what we’re here referring to as continuous interest, you need to take the limit as these time periods get smaller and smaller (i.e. where you can think of the time periods as being infinitesimal). So, we don’t actually have fixed time periods any more! It’s just that at every single instant in time the instantaneous rate of change of your money due to interest is exactly $r$.

Comment: The function r depends on the variable t,am I right?

Comment: If I'm correct the overall interest rate approaches $e^r$ *per year* with continuous compounding. For example, if $r$ is $5\%$ per year, then the continuous compounding interest approaches $e^{0.05}$ per year. But here we seem to treat $r$ as the the simple interest per year, right?  I'm still not able to see how  $r$ represents the instantaneous rate  of the account @JackCrawford

Comment: @vic165 $r$ is constant in the problem

Comment: @pooja Quite literally from the equation you wrote, the instantaneous rate that your money is changing $dy/dt$ is equal to $ry$ where $y$ is the amount of money you have that instant. Separating variables and then integrating we find a solution of $y=y_0 e^{rt}$ describes your amount of money at any time $t$ given initial money $y_0$. You’re right that the dimension of $r$ will have to correspond to your choice of dimension in $t$, but unlike in simple interest this choice won’t change the (continuous) shape of the function (it’ll just “zoom” in or out).

Comment: Oh then $ry$ is the instantaneous rate of $y$, and $r$ is the interest per $t=1 unit$. Hope I get this. Thank you so much. You're really awesome! If you had time and posted it as answer I'd love to make it best.

Comment: You can’t really correspond between the simple interest per year and this compound, continuous interest since they have different shapes. If $t= 1 \textrm{ year}$, and $r$ is in units $\$/\textrm{year}$, then after exactly a year you’ll have $e^r$ as much money as you had when you started. So you can approximate the compound interest using simple interest, I guess, but in the case of simple interest the person doesn’t actually gain any interest in their account until the end of the period. In continuous, they do.